# error in sql query in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I do a find :all in the controller, my view shows the query result also. Which I dont want it to show. However when I am doing the same thing with params :id its not showing the query result. How do I not show the query result using find :all?

This is the part where I am rendering it. My videos/ _show.html.erb has the following code.

```
<table id="topics" style="border:1px solid black"> 
  <%= videos.each do |video|%> 
    <tr> 
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" onclick=change(<%= video.video_time%>)>
        <%= video.topic%>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <%= video.video_time%>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

The view is:

```
[#<Video id: 1, video_url: "/RandyPausch.flv", topic: "Looks around", created_at: "2011-06-13 09:58:00", updated_at: "2011-06-13 09:58:00", timeline: "156.177", video_time: "156.177">] Looks around   156.177 as  0.133 kljdd 0.133
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: You need some more details if you want good answers.  Show us the controller code in question as well as the view code that it's rendering, and we might be able to help you.  Also show us what you mean when you say one version "shows the query result" and the other version doesn't.

Comment: <%= render :partial=>"videos/show" , :locals=>{:videos=>Video.find(:all)}%>

Comment: This is the part where I am rendering it.
My videos/ _show.html.erb has the following code.
<table id="topics" style="border:1px solid black">
<%= videos.each do |video|%>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" onclick=change(<%= video.video_time%>)><%= video.topic%></td>
 <td><%= video.video_time%> </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
The view is
[#<Video id: 1, video_url: "/RandyPausch.flv", topic: "Looks around", created_at: "2011-06-13 09:58:00", updated_at: "2011-06-13 09:58:00", timeline: "156.177", video_time: "156.177">]
Looks around 156.177
as 0.133
kljdd 0.133

Comment: You can edit your original question to add detail like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you do not use the equal sign (=) when including embedded ruby for which you do not want to print results.  Specifically, remove the = from the `videos.each do |video|` line, like so:

```
<table id="topics" style="border:1px solid black"> 
  <% videos.each do |video|%> 
    <tr> 
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" onclick=change(<%= video.video_time%>)><%= video.topic%></td> 
      <td><%= video.video_time%> </td> 
    </tr> 
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
<%= videos.each do |video| %>
```

There should not be the '=', so:

```
<% videos.each do |video| %>
```